# Children's book, part of a series, set on a ship

Tags: story-identification

I remember reading this in the 2000s. I only remember random details of it:

-Beginning of the book is set on a ship. I think it was a frame narrative, in which the rest of the story is being told on the ship.

-The book was from the middle of a series

-Involved crossing a lake or area by using chains from the ceiling

-Involved climbing a tower. In one scene a character had to climb out a ledge and scale the tower from the outside.

-Had an old woman that gave the children a soup that was viscous, creamy, yellow, and sweet

Sorry, thats all I can think of right now.

Comment: Can you remember any of the fantasy elements?